# In Angular, how to display the content/text from a select option value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

In Angular, how do you display the content/text of an option in a select list? For example, you have `{{ data.singleSelect }}` that displays the `value` of an option, but how do you use it to display the content/text of that option instead?

Code on Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/cCAHfWL275EZTZt9epUR?p=preview :

```
<body ng-app="staticSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="singleSelect"> Single select: </label><br>
    <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect">
      <option value="option-1">Thing 1</option>
      <option value="option-2">Thing 2</option>
    </select><br>


    <tt>singleSelect = {{data.singleSelect}}</tt>
    <p>Update above so 'Thing 1' or 'Thing 2' displayed instead of 'option-1' or 'option-2'</p>


  </form>
</div>
</body>
```

I want to keep the markup of options in in the HTML. (If this against Angular best practices, please let me know). And want to keep values on the option so they can be used as filters.

Comment: in your case - you can't. But if you create `select` dynamically - you can bind it to object and then show needed filed from this object

Comment: Change your `select` to use `objects` instead of text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller

```
$scope.options = [
    {
        name: "Thing 1",
        value: "option-1"
    },
    {
        name: "Thing 2",
        value: "option-2"
    }
];
```

HTML

```
<select ng-model="data.singleSelect" ng-options="option as option.name for option in options"/>
```

Your value

```
{{data.singleSelect.name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your controller

```
$scope.allData = {
'option-1': 'Thing 1',
'option-2': 'Thing 2'
}
```

inside your HTML

```
<tt>singleSelect = {{allData[data.singleSelect]}}</tt>
```

Comment: It would be better if you use $scope.allData inside ng-repeat for populate select - options

Answer (score 0):

You can just omit the value attribute of option tag.

```
<body ng-app="staticSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="singleSelect"> Single select: </label><br>
    <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect">
      <option>Thing 1</option>
      <option>Thing 2</option>
    </select><br>


    <tt>singleSelect = {{data.singleSelect}}</tt>
    <p>Update above so 'Thing 1' or 'Thing 2' displayed instead of 'option-1' or 'option-2'</p>


  </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Interesting workaround. I want to keep the value though, for cases like using the values for sorting. Example like using orderBy:orderProp in this tutorial https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04  -- There a way to use data.singleSelect and then another filter or something to display the content/text instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant: dynamically create *select* like this:

```
<select name="singleSelect"  ng-init="ops=[{v:'option-1', l:'thing 1'},{v:'option-2', l:'thing 2'}]" ng-options="o.l for o in ops"  ng-model="data.singleSelect">
</select>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/if22AOntSQqjEFa9S71Q?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng options` in an angular js way.

Here is the plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/pGqzwhvkOO0iXYvmdlOj?p=preview

Comment: There a way to do something like that while keeping the HTML to define the option tags? Or is it considered better practice in Angular to put the options into the controller?

Comment: @jpostdesign Using ng options and creating it dynamically from a model would be a better option to do. In future if you need some other value, then you can directly use it from model.

Comment: It's been made as link now.Thanks,